# How to scroll the images left and right in ASP.NET, using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am developing an application in Asp.net, where I need to do a scrolling of images.
The images will be loaded from a folder using server side code.

Assuming there are 20 images in the folder, the page should show only 5 images and the others should be shown when scrolling towards Left or Right Arrow's [image]

Not sure, how to achieve this using javascript or jquery. Any ideas ??

Comment: You may try with the plugin  like http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-contentthumbnail-slder-v2-0-jscarousel-v2-0/

Comment: Check this out: http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html